# Integrate SOAP/SVC service API in Android

Tags: android, api, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Below is the c# code which is need to converted in Java/Android API call:

```
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)


        {

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);

            if (req.Credentials != null)

            {

                NetworkCredential cred = req.Credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Username");

                req.Headers.Add("XMS_LOGON_USER", cred.UserName);

                req.Headers.Add("XMS_AUTH_PASSWORD", cred.Password);

                req.Headers.Add("XMS_LICENSETYPE", "Device");

                req.Headers.Add("XMS_DEVICE_NUM", XMSData.Device.Instance.DeviceNo());

                req.Headers.Add("XMS_DEVICE_OEM", XMSData.Device.Instance.OEM());

                req.Headers.Add("XMS_DEVICE_OS", XMSData.Device.Instance.OperatingSystem());

#if PROXYDEBUG

                //this is for working with fiddler. Fiddler must be running when debugging in PROXYDEBUG configuration

                req.Proxy = new WebProxy("ppp_peer", 8888);

#endif

                if (cookieManager.CookieValues.Count > 0)

                    cookieManager.PublishCookies(req);

            }

            return req;

        }
```

I am having trouble in understanding this line of code and how could I pass this in KSOAP2 android.

> NetworkCredential cred = req.Credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Username");

When i pass this in header, API is throwing 404 error. Also this API is BasicHttpBinding along with Security mode set to “Transport”.

Thanks in advance.